# How to Turn Off Water Softener Recharge Schedule

Tags: plumbing, water-softener

I have a GE GXSF40H water softener in use at my cottage.

It automatically recharges overnight.

I want to prevent it from doing that (and just use the manual recharge feature) as we're typically only at our cottage on weekends. I prefer a manual recharge so as to not waste salt during the week when no water is in use. I know how to do a manual recharge, but I can't find any instruction on how to prevent the scheduled automatic nightly recharge.

The manual (http://pdfstream.manualsonline.com/d/dfe8864c-63f3-4dd7-8f62-9d91804242f8.pdf) doesn't specify how to do that.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this (or know if it's even possible?)

Comment: Pull the plug when you leave for the week typically works, on a basic level. Upgrading to a model that actually monitors use rather than fixed time recharge would be another solution. Using an external weekly timer to turn it on Friday and off Sunday (or whatever works with your weekend schedule) would be another solution.

Comment: Yes, cutting the power is my backup plan, but was curious if there was a way via programming the control

Comment: That depends on the control. Since you stated that there was no such instruction in the manual, probably that particular control cannot. So, upgrade (replace) it or kill its power seem to be the available choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding as to how your Water Softener works.  According to the manual (page 14): "After a period of time, the resin beads become
coated with hard minerals and they have to be
cleaned. This cleaning is called recharge.
Recharge is started at 2:00 AM (factory setting)
by the water softening system control, and
consists of five stages or cycles."

This means that the Recharge will start at 2:00 AM unless you change that setting but it doesn't happen every night.  It will only happen when "the water softening system control" determines that it is necessary to clean the resin beads. Thus if you haven't been using water, the beads will be clean and recharging will not take place.

Comment: No, I owned GE GXSF40H, and it recharge every night and wasted 55 Gallons/day. This will cost 3 time higher to change water heater every 6 years (EXP:$600 / gas water heater /6 year x 3= $1800. and cost for 55G/Day x 365 days = 20,075 Gallons = 26.8 HCF x $4= $108 x6 years =$644 + salt ?)
I don't see to save any money to use water softener!

Comment: Page 16 of the manual indicates that this is an automatic recharge water softener. i.e. It recharges only when it _needs_ to, not every night. If your softener was recharging every night, either you were using a _lot_ of water each day, or there was something wrong with the settings of the softener or there was a failure in the softener itself.

Comment: @FreeMan One other option: it is working as designed, and it is designed really poorly.